# Map int to Template int

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a more elegant solution (to a hopefully obvious problem) than

```
switch(variableInt)
{
    case 0: tmpl<0>::foo(); break;
    case 1: tmpl<1>::foo(); break;
    // up to, say, 10
}
```

Clearly, this can only be defined in some range. I only found old topics around this, maybe some nice C++17 or C++20 feature that helps us out here?

Comment: You might find the techniques in [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0376r0.html) handy.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t I>
int foo(int arg) {
    return I * arg;
}

template<std::size_t ...Is>
auto get_foo(std::index_sequence<Is...>, int i) {
    return *(std::initializer_list<int(*)(int)>{&foo<Is>...}.begin() + i);
}

int foo(std::size_t i, int arg) {
    return get_foo(std::make_index_sequence<11>(), i)(arg);
}
```

Here's another solution that optimizes more nicely:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t I>
int foo(int arg) {
    return I * arg;
}

template<std::size_t ...Is>
auto foo(std::index_sequence<Is...>, int i, int arg) {
    int ret;
    ((Is == i && (ret = foo<Is>(arg))), ...);
    return ret;
}

int foo(std::size_t i, int arg) {
    return foo(std::make_index_sequence<11>(), i, arg);
}
```

Comment: is `initializer_list` optimized away in this setting? It is generally quite slow, so this does not seem to be the templated equivalent to the code in my original question

Comment: @IceFire I added another solution that is potentially better.